# Duda con nodeJS y angular

Tags: javascript, nodejs, angular, mongodb

tengo la siguiente duda, he estado desarrollando un login algo basico y pues ya lo tengo casi listo creeria yo, pero pues tengo mis dudas respecto a unos temas.

Lo primero es que quisiera saber si hay una forma de que Angular 6 detecta un error HTTP, por ejemplo, cuando hay un error en el correo o contraseña el backend me manda un status(409), quisiera saber si es posible que Angular 6 obtenga este error y mostrar un sweetalert.

También quisiera saber como es posible enviar el nombre de la persona que logeo en ese momento y mostrarlo en una etiqueta despues de pasar el proceso del login.

Este es mi codigo del login:

```
userController.logInUser = async (req, res) => {
    const { email } = req.body;
    const user = await model_user.findOne({ email });
    if (!user) {
        return res.status(401).send("El correo no existe");
    } else {
        const match = await bcrypt.compare(req.body.password, user.password);
        if (match) {
            const token = jwt.sign({ _id: user._id}, secretKey);
            res.status(200).json({ token })
        } else {
            return res.status(401).send("Contraseña erronea");
        }
    }
}
```

Y este es el componente del login, quisiera saber si en la parte de err=> es posible poner un condicional que compare si se obtuvo tal codigo para mostrar un sweetalert adecuado

```
signIn() {
    this.authService.signIn(this.user)
      .subscribe(
        res => {
          localStorage.setItem('token', res.token);
          this.router.navigate(['/private-games'])
          Swal.fire(
            'Bienvenido',
            '',
            'success'
          )

        },
        err => {
          console.log(err)
          Swal.fire({
            icon: 'error',
            title: 'Error',
            text: 'No se ha podido iniciar sesion, verifique su correo y contraseña',
          })
        }
      );
  }
```

Pensaba que al iniciar sesion podria poner en el app-component.html algo como esto y que mostrara ahi el nombre de la persona que acaba de logear:

```
<a class="nav-link" routerLink="/profile" routerLinkActive="active" >{{nombre_usuario}}</a>
```

Comment: en mi opinión, lo que hago yo primero es validar los primero desde el frontend para enviar los datos limpios y luego otra validación en el backend para tener simplemente mas seguridad;
tu estas diciendo que estas recibiendo un error `HTTP` con el status `409`y luego preguntas como obtener ese error, no se entiende muy bien, recibes el estado de la solicitud o no la recibes?

Comment: Hola Enzo no sé si me explique muy bien lo que quiero decir es que la validación la hago en el backend, al haber un error, mando un error 409, el cual pues me lo muestre en la consola, lo que quiero saber es que si hay alguna forma de en angular capturar ese error y usar un condicional que me muestre algo respecto al código de ese error.

Comment: que es lo que muestra por consola `err` ?

Comment: Cuando genero el error, ese err no muestra nada, lo unico que imprime es esta linea `return res.status(401).send("El correo no existe");`

Comment: prueba quitando el `return`, `res.status(401)` lo que hace es enviar un `status` como respuesta, seguido de `send()`, prueba quitando el return, valga la redundancia

Comment: Okey y luego en el angular como la obtendria? para poder hacer algo por ejemplo, si el error es 401 pues imprime, el correo no existe así

Comment: Puedes hacerlo con un siempre condicional `if`,`if (err.message == "El correo no existe ") //logica para manejar tu error`, sencillo no?

Comment: Si, gracias, lo probare

Comment: hay un detalle a resolver, preguntaste como puedes mostrar los datos del usuario, lo mas factible seria crear una verificacion del token en el backend para que cada peticion tenga una cabezera con ese token y asi extraer los datos que conincidan con ese id y devolver los datos que desees

Comment: Eso estaba pensando, pero la verdad no se como enviar ademas del token los datos del usuario en la cabecera

Comment: te preparare un ejemplo

Comment: Excelente, gracias por tu ayuda

Comment: Justo acabo de probar lo que me dijiste sobre quitarle el return a lo de res.status y pues, no se sucede nada, debido a que el err.message que me trae a la hora de introducir un email inexistente es **Http failure response for http://localhost:3000/signin: 409 Conflict** y lo que trataba de comparar era el `No correo no existe` que habia en el back

Answer (score 1):

Para poder verificar una peticion al servidor, es conveniente saber si el usuario tiene permisos para poder acceder a cierta peticion, podriamos crear una funcion para poder crear esa verifican de la siguiente manera:

```
Function VerifyToken(req, res, next){
  if(!req.Headers.Authorization){
     return res.status(400). json({err: 'No tienes permiso para realizar dicha peticion'})
  }

  const token = req.Headers.Authorization.split(' ')[1]
  if(token == "" || null){
      return res.status(400). json({err: 'No tienes permiso para realizar dicha peticion'})
  }
  const payload = jwt.verify(token, 'clave secreta del token')
  req.userId = payload._id;
  next()
}
```

Bien, haremos un repaso de lo que acabo de hacer, simplemente se crea una funcion para verificar si existe un token o no, el la linea `const token = req.Headers.Authorization.split(' ')[1]` lo que suce es que en una constante token extraemos y guardaos el token, desde el frontend lo llamaremos `Authorization` que contendra lo siguiente `Bearer token`, usaremos el texto `Bearer` para seguir con el estandar, seguido de un espacio y el token, el `.split(' ')` lo que hace es separar el texto y con el [1] simplemente obtenemos el segundo dato, osea el token, y como el `req` puede ser extendido, simplemente le agregaomso un nuevo metodo llamado `userId` que contendra el id del usuario, la funcion que creamos la llamaremos despues de la ruta y antes de la funcion:

```
router.post('dataUser', VerifyToken, (req, res)=>{
  //si el token existe y esta todo correcto podremos acceder al id del usuario de la siguiente forma 
  console.log(req.userId)
```

})

//De esta forma estarias verificando el token del usuario y su permiso para poder realizar peticiones, es una verificacion muy sencilla.

desde el frontend lo que tendriamos que hacer es crear una cabecera para que al realizar una peticion se envie la cabecera llamada `Authorization` para poder verificar la autenticacion del usuario y no tener ningun problema al enviar datos desde el backend,
en un servicio lo que haremos es simplemente crear un metodo que retorne el token que tenemos guardado en el `localStorage`:

```
getToken(){
return localStorage.getItem('token')
```

}

//Podriamos crear dicha accion en este mismo archivo pero en mi caso yo siempre lo hago en otro servicio a parte de la sigueonre manera:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core'
import { HttpInterceptor } from '@angular/common/http'

import class TokenInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {

constructor(
 private auth: AuthService
){}

 intercept(req, next){
  const token = req.clone({
   setHeaders: {
    Authorization: `Bearer ${this.Auth.getToken()}` 
   }
  }
 })

 return next.handle(token)

}
```

//Lo que hacemos aca es simplemente obtener el token desde el `AuthServices` desde el metodo `getToken` Y Lo concatenamos con el texto bearer, lo ultimo que faltaria es importar este metodo el al `app.Module` de la siguiente manera:

```
providers: [
 {
   provider: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, //Este modulo se importa desde '@angular/common/http'
   useClass: TokenInterceptor, //aqui agregamos la clase que contiene el metodo intercept
   multi: true
 }
]
```

//de esta forma tendremos una cabecera que contenga el token y poder realizar peticiones con una cabezera incluida que contenga el token, obviamente, hay muchos temas de seguridad al hablar sobre tokens, ya que se esta guardando en el navegador y el suario puede obtenerlo y desifrarlo si tiene dichos conocimientos, espero que te sirva este ejemplo, saludos.